# How can I call a navigated Fragment's function in the Activity hosting the fragment via JetPack's Navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I switched from FragmentManager's transactions to JetPack's Navigation architecture component. In doing so I can no longer call: findFragmentById(int) so that I can get a reference to the instantiated fragment and thus call it's functions from within the Activity that hosts it.

The reason for this is that I am unable to get my custom DialogFragment's to implement listeners inside the fragments themselves so I have them implemented in Main Actiity. When the DialogFragment is interacted, I want it to notify the fragment to call some functions. But because I can not register listeners in Fragment itself, it is completely unaware that the user has clicked the "cancel" or "confirm" buttons.

The activity is aware of the user's actions from the DialogFragment, it should be able to then notify the Fragment so that Fragment may call it's functions.

How do I get a reference to the navigated fragment so that I may call its functions?

Answer (score 0):

First please check my understanding of your question as that's baseline for my answer:

1. You have activity
2. It hosts fragment
3. That fragment opens dialog fragment and would like to know user's dialog result

If the above is correct, then I don't think navigation currently supports something like this out of the box however you can:

1. Use shared view model (at the activity level for example), that has some sort of one time live data, to which fragment is subscribed and dialog fragment sends its choice. So basically when dialog fragment changes live data, hosting fragment (or any other subscribers) automatically receives the change
2. Use plain old event bus like Otto and just subscribe to event at the fragment level and emit event inside your dialog fragment?

PS.: here is possible one time data structure:

```
class OneTimeLiveData<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {

    private val pending = AtomicBoolean(false)

    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
        super.observe(owner, Observer { t ->
            if (pending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                observer.onChanged(t)
            }
        })
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun setValue(t: T?) {
        pending.set(true)
        super.setValue(t)
    }

    @MainThread
    fun call() {
        value = null
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using onActivityResult() in conjunction with setTargetFragment() so that the targeted fragment is notified via onActivityResult(). After I click Confirm the Fragment can do whatever it wants. I am wondering if I am using onActivityResult() for the wrong reasons though. From what I gather though ViewModel is the correct way to do this based on Google searches.

Comment: Upon doing this method, I can remove any of the listeners in the MainActivity and thus remove all implementations/declarations from the DialogFragment (such as onDialogOptionSelected() ) as MainActivity does not need to know of the Dialog being pressed. I'm still having doubts if I am doing things wrong.

Comment: I was using the approach (onActivityResult/setTargetFragment) before navigation components. How are you able to setTargetFrgment with navigation components? In my case dialog is just another node of graph and I am not showing it manually, thus cannot set target.

Comment: I did not set any DialogFragments as a navigation node. Maybe that will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to call the function in fragment from activity in an application works with navigation component. I call the code below like that.

```
val searchFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments[0].childFragmentManager.fragments[0] as SearchFragment
searchFragment.setSearchText(obj.getOriginalValue())
```

Comment: If you use Glide, this can break.